# Overclocking: Memory clock changed after changing FSB from 333 to 400 MHz?

Tags: memory, cpu, overclocking

I'm trying to overclock an old system with an Intel Core2Duo E8500 from 3.16 GHz to 3.8 GHz. I was able to do that by changing the FSB from 333 MHz to 400 MHz and raising the VCore to 1.3125. Now I noticed something strange: HWiNFO64 is showing the memory clock as 600 MHz now (400x1.5). Before changing the FSB it was 400 MHz (333x1.2). Is my memory really overclocked by 50% now? Is this bad for the RAM? Is there a way to get it to 400 MHz again? Or is HWiNFO64 just showing wrong information?

- Before overclocking my cpu: http://www.userbenchmark.com/UserRun/6646727
- After overclocking my cpu: http://www.userbenchmark.com/UserRun/6647131

The memory performance is a bit better after overclocking.

Comment: This depends on your motherboard. Usually motherboards have 2 or 3 different modes you run your memory speed in. One of them is that it is tied to the FSB like you see. The most important piece of information you could've provided is missing - your motherboard model.

Comment: Use cpu-z to read the SPD chip on the memory to see what the memory can handle.

Comment: The model of the mainboard can be seen in the benchmark: "Gigabyte GA-EP45-DS3". CPU-Z is telling me the memory can handle 266/333/400 MHz. At 400 MHz 5.0 CAS# Latency, 5 RAS# to CAS#, 5 RAS# Precharge, 15 tRAS, 23 tRC. It has always been running at CL4-4-4-12 at 400 MHz.